# Not getting Kubernetes cluster option in Create Server Group of Spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am using Spinnaker version 1.26.6 which is deployed using Halyard.
I have added multiple Kubernetes account with provider version V2 following here https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/install/providers/kubernetes-v2/ and the service account has entire cluster access.
While clicking on `Create Server Group` in UI, I don't get option to select my kubernetes accounts added. I get something like this
[image: Create Server Group]

This account has empty dropdown list.
Is there any way by which instead of this prompt I get to choose my kubernetes accounts which I have added and deployed applications to?

Answer (score 0):

We skipped this manual step of user grants.

```
https://spinnaker.io/docs/setup/productionize/persistence/clouddriver-sql/#database-setup
```

After adding this, it took sometime to sync and we are able to get the required results.